# Returning acf plots in combination with purrr::map R

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, advanced-custom-fields

I am exploring some behavioral time series nested at ID level and using purrr::map to produce autocorrelation plots (acf, pacf) for each ID.

```
df_acf <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(acf_obj = map(data, ~ acf(.$value, na.action = na.pass, lag.max = length(.$value))))
```

When I explore the acf_obj for each ID (e.g., `df_acf$acf_obj[[1]]`) I see the autocorrelation and lag arrays but not the plot (which is produced by default). I know that acf() returns a acf object and not a plot but I am trying to figure out if there is a way to save the acf plot as product of acf() used in combination with map::purrr.
I am not looking for other ways to plot the results of acf() like using ggplot to plot lag, autocorrelation, and ci values from acf().

Thank you

Comment: If the plot you want is a side-effect of the `acf` function, you could try replacing `map` with `purrr::walk`. This works in the same way as `map` but returns the function's side-effects.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback - if a switch and use `purrr::walk` instead of `purrr::map`, it returns the nested df, in a way that `df_acf$acf_obj[[1]]` provides the same output as `df_acf$data[[1]]` - from purrr reference functions: `walk()` calls `.f` for its side-effect and returns the input `.x`